# How to make jQuery .click function more scaleable

Tags: jquery

I am having a little trouble getting this to work. I have several anchor tags on a page that use scrollTop for its animation. HTML example

link

```
<a id="TOS" href="#Svc">What are your terms of service?</a>
```

and the target

```
<div class="tabWrapp" name="TOS" id="Svc">
<!-- /tos tabWrapp --></div>
```

and the jquery

```
$('a#TOS').bind('click',function() {
     var pos = $('#Svc').offset().top;
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : pos}, 500);
     return false;  //stops navigation from adding the id to the url
   });
```

Now this gets quite bloated having 30+ of these on the same page. Could I modify the code to apply a class to the anchor and make a variable out of the url like so

```
$('.foo').bind('click', function() {
var href = (this).attr('ID');
var pos = href.offset().top;
$('html,body').animate9{scrollTop : pos}, 500);
return false;
});
```

the issue Im having is targeting the anchor ID inside the href var and then placing that inside the pos var...thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give all those links the same class, like this:

```
<a class="scrollTo" href="#Svc">What are your terms of service?</a>
```

Then make your function bind to that class, like this:

```
$('a.scrollTo').bind('click',function() {
  var pos = $(this.hash).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : pos}, 500);
  return false;
});
```

This binds to all the links but uses the `.hash` of the link you clicked on to get the scrollTop destination.

Comment: You know, for all the JS/html I do... I never once thought to use the `hash` property of an anchor.

Comment: @mway - It has the `#` already, so it makes a great ID selector...and degrades gracefully with JS disabled to boot, win-win :)

Comment: I recommend using `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`. More about why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you mean, yes you can. You have to use the hash function in javascript.

So for your markup, if you have

```
<a class="foo" id="TOS" href="#Svc">What are your terms of service?</a>
```

This JS will alert "#Svc" :

```
$('a.foo').click(function() {
     alert(this.hash);
   });
```

So in your example, use it to make :

```
$('a.foo').click(function() {
  var pos = $(this.hash).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : pos}, 500);
  return false;
});
```

By the way, you can use

```
.click(function() {});
```

as a shortcut for

```
.bind('click', function() {});
```

More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the ID for that kind of thing before but maybe you could try using `title` instead? And then you would just use it in the selector like `$(my_title).offset().top`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the element by Id first:

```
$('.foo').bind('click', function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('ID');
  var pos = $('#'+href).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : pos}, 500);
  return false;
});
```

adding `$('#element')` around the `href` should do it, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[ID]').bind('click', function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var pos = $(href).offset().top;
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop : pos}, 500);
return false;
});
```

Worked for me.  I adjusted the href var.  Pretty sure that was it.  `a[ID]` as a selector targets any anchors with IDs.